# Changing a boolean when switching views with a TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am attempting to have a TabView which can be swiped across to switch between one of the two pages. At the top of my view, i have two buttons to switch between each TabView which is all working correctly.

I am trying to create a slider that will change positions from under the button that indicates the left page to the button that indicates the right page.

I currently have this working however only when i press the button to change view, and not when i slide to change the view. Basically, my question is is it possible to change the boolean that controls the slider when the page is changed on the tab view

Code:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var tabIndex = 0
    @State var showMe = false
    @State var barw = true
    
    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                Image("top")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                HStack(spacing: 0){
                Button("Overview"){
                    tabIndex = 0
                    withAnimation{
                        barw.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 210, height: 55, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=View@*/Color(red: 0.828, green: 0.284, blue: 0.248)/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                
                
                Button("Details"){
                    tabIndex = 1
                    withAnimation{
                        barw.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 210, height: 55, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=View@*/Color(red: 0.828, green: 0.284, blue: 0.248)/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
                VStack{
                HStack{
                    
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.988, green: 0.99, blue: 0.63))
                    .frame(width: 210, height: 4)
                    .offset(x: barw ? 0 : 210)
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
                    Spacer()
                }
                    Spacer()
                }
               Spacer()
            }.zIndex(1)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Spacer()
                TabView(selection: $tabIndex){
                    page1()
                        .tag(0)
                        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
                    page2()
                        .tag(1)
                        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
                }.tabViewStyle(.page)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: This is already handled by the OS. Just add `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())` on the `TabView`

Comment: This doesn’t answer my question nor is helpful

Comment: Tie the change of the `Bool` to the change of the tab selection. When you swipe between pages, the `Bool` will change. Or you can simply bind the slider to the `tabIndex`. and change the slider based on that value.

Comment: Do you think you could give me an example of how to change the slider based on the tabIndex? currently i've just got ```.offset(x: barw ? 0 : 210)``` how would i make it so the offset changes when tabIndex switches from 0 to 1? Sorry, i'm quite new to swiftui.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, I found using `.onChange` to work perfectly.
Using:

```
.onChange(of: tabIndex) { newValue in
    barw.toggle()
}
```

Comment: That is the answer. When you post code, if you want someone to provide a code answer, you need to post a  [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).